# React Navigation goBack with key

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Currently, React Navigation only supports `goBack(key)` which indicates it will go back to the screen previous to the screen supplied.

I have `Checkout -> Shipping -> Payment -> Review` screens, where it will take the user straight from `Checkout` to `Review` if shipping and payment information have already been recorded. However, on `Review`, if I want to edit shipping information, I would need to do `goBack(payment-screen-key)`, which I have no access to because the user never navigated to the payment screen (thus, no way of storing that key in redux).

Upon searching react-navigation github issues, it doesn't seem like there's a clean way of accomplishing this task. Is there a way to do essentially `navigate(routeName)` but not add another screen to the stack?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually you're not going back when you want to edit the shipping information from the review screen if you've gone straight from `Checkout` to `Review`, so as you mention backing to that screen doesn't work, and wouldn't make sense.

What about instead re-thinking your checkout flow? For example navigate from `Review` to the section you want to edit without the possibility to advance from there.

`Checkout -> Review -> EditShippingInformation -> goBack(Review) -> EditPaymentInformation -> goBack(Review) -> End`

Where `EditShippingInformation` and `EditPaymentInformation` includes a form with a save button that leads back to the `Review` screen rather than `navigate`s forward to the `Review` screen. Perhaps these `EditShippingInformation` and `EditPaymentInformation` screens could be dialogs even?